# Where is the mongos config database string being stored?

Tags: mongodb

I made a mistake in my mongo sharding setup - I had an error in my config database string. I tried to clean this up by deleting all the data in the config database servers, and restarting all the mongod services. However, even after restarting mongos I still initially get an error like this,

When I run :

```
sh.status():
```

I get :

```
mongos specified a different config database string : stored : <old string here>
```

Where is this this string actually being stored? I tried looking for it in the config databases themselves and also the members of the shard, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Mongod/shards cache it in memory. You need to restart them.

Answer (score 7):

As at MongoDB 2.4, the `--configsvr` string specified for the `mongos` servers is also cached in-memory on the shard `mongod` servers.  In order for `mongos` servers to join a sharded cluster, they must have an [identical config string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-sharded-clusters/#config-database-string-error) (including order of hostnames).

There is a tutorial in the MongoDB manual to [Migrate Config Servers with Different Hostnames](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/migrate-config-servers-with-different-hostnames/) which covers the full process, including migrating a config server to a new host (which isn't applicable in your case).

If you are still seeing the "different config database string" error after restarting everything, it's likely that you had a least one rogue `mongod` or `mongos` running during the process.

To resolve this error:

- shut down all the `mongod` processes (for the shards)
- shut down the `mongos` processes
- restart the `mongod` processes (for the shards)
- restart the `mongos` with the correct `--configsvr` string